# add the same menu to multiple windows with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a program with Qt.
I have a QMainWindow and a function called createMenus() that returns a QMenuBar*.

Within the class MainWindow : QMainWindow, I call: this->setMenuBar(createMenus());

So I have a beautiful MainWindow with a menu in the top.

Now, in "File", I want to put a button that creates a new window (presumably a QWidget?).
And I would like to show the same MenuBar in the top part of my new window.

```
void MainWindow::createWindow()
{
    QWidget* window = new QWidget;

    QVBoxLayout* center_box = new QVBoxLayout;
    center_box->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    center_box->setSpacing(0);

#ifndef Q_OS_MAC
    QMenuBar* newMenu = createMenus();
    center_box->setMenuBar(newMenu);
#endif

    window->setLayout(center_box);
}
```

This works (in Linux), as a QMenuBar is shown in the new window.
The aftereffect is that the QMenuBar in the MainWindow has disappeared.

Can someone direct me to the best implementation to create multiple windows with the same QMenuBar?

Comment: you have to create the new menus using `new` otherwise the other window takes ownership

Comment: Hi @deW1, how can I? Now, within createMenus() I have the function "bar = new QMenuBar()", and "return bar;". So, technically, *newMenu is always a new menu. The result, is that the above code doesn't display any menu on the new window.

Comment: Show us more code, e.g. by creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the very least we would need to see your code for `createMenus()`, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: What I do is create a method that creates the new QMenuBar and populates it, and just call that method once from the constructor of each window.  That way each window then has its own QMenuBar, but they are all identical and there is no code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked up your issue and noticed the same behaviour, however you cannot simply copy the existing `QMenuBar` of your `QMainWindow`.

You could however use a factory method like you did, but you have to assure that you don't return **an empty** `QMenuBar`, otherwise the menu won't show up.

Possible implementation:

```
QMenuBar* MainWindow::createMenu()
{
    QMenuBar *menu = new QMenuBar();


    menu->addMenu("Test0");
    menu->addMenu("Test1");
    menu->addMenu("Test2");
    menu->addMenu("Test3");

    return menu;
}
```

And then in your method you can do:

```
void MainWindow::createWindow()
{
    QWidget* window = new QWidget;

    QVBoxLayout* center_box = new QVBoxLayout;

#ifndef Q_OS_MAC
    center_box->setMenuBar(createMenu());
#endif

    window->setLayout(center_box);
    window->show();
}
```

---

Another way would be to subclass `QMenuBar`, which is however more suitable if you want to create a specific kind of implementation or add to the functionality of the already existing class.

custommenubar.h

```
#ifndef CUSTOMMENUBAR_H
#define CUSTOMMENUBAR_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMenuBar>

class CustomMenuBar : public QMenuBar
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit CustomMenuBar();
};

#endif // CUSTOMMENUBAR_H
```

---

custommenubar.cpp

```
#include "custommenubar.h"

CustomMenuBar::CustomMenuBar()
{
    addMenu("Test");
    addMenu("1");
    addMenu("2");
    addMenu("3");
}
```

---

And then in your method:

```
void MainWindow::createWindow()
{
    QWidget* window = new QWidget;

    QVBoxLayout* center_box = new QVBoxLayout;

#ifndef Q_OS_MAC
    QMenuBar* newMenu = new CustomMenuBar();
    center_box->setMenuBar(newMenu);
#endif

    window->setLayout(center_box);
    window->show();
}
```

---

Make sure you take care of cleaning everything up :)

Comment: I did. The answer still strongly advertises subclassing for the purpose of populating a menu bar. Of course that is _valid_, but
bad on several levels, compared to using a factory function:
1. It creates a lot of unnecessary code noise,
2. It adds another moc and compiler call, adding to compile and link time,
3. It adds half a dozen symbols (class, constructor, meta object+functions) instead of 1 for just a function, adding to binary size and load time,
4. It makes code sharing harder (think creating MyMenuBar1 and MyMenuBar2 with partially shared items)

Comment: @E4z9 I can swap it around later and include a factory method.